# c# webrequest to google geocoding api returns different result than browser

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have a really weird problem with the google geocoding webservice. I want to use it in my c# project to geocode an entered address server side. So far so good, but i ran into an address which doesn´t want to be geocoded that way. Every other address i tested (even the chinese ones) are returning the same result as google maps itself.

This is my essential Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Gerdestr.%2B1%2C%2B58454%2C%2BWitten%2C%2BGermany&components=country:Germany") as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

The url-string is actually generated by code, but that´s the one that troubles me. It is an existing German address, but the resulting json I get is:

```
{
"results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Germany",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Germany",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 55.058347,
                  "lng" : 15.0418962
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.2701115,
                  "lng" : 5.8663425
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.165691,
               "lng" : 10.451526
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 55.058347,
                  "lng" : 15.0418962
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 47.2701115,
                  "lng" : 5.8663425
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJa76xwh5ymkcRW-WRjmtd6HU",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

It´s a bit generally and fit on every address in Germany ^^.

The weird thing is when i use the same string with my browser then it returns the correct result. It is like the address parameter is empty, but as you can see its not.

Any ideas? I´m out of it. Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the request/response that gets generated in your code using something like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make sure the request is what you think it is and compared to that your making in your browser?

Comment: I caught the packages using wireshark. The only difference between browser and the server side request are the additional header infos the browser sends. The weird thing is, that the same code works for so many other adresses. This is the first one i discovered making problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your request. The streetname should be "gerde**s**str.".

The geocoding api can correct this errors if you provide the address information in a slightly different order:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=1+Gerdestr.,+58454+Witten,+Germany") as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and sorry for my late reply. It was a bit stressful at work the last days.

Comment: Actually google made a mistake. Its "gerdestraße" but google has listet it as "gerdesstraße". You are right with the order of the address components, but all other adresses i tried it didn´t made a difference. In this case only, it does. And this only server side. If you copy the url and paste it into your browser the json response is what i need.

The Problem is: I only have one textbox where the customer can enter his address and it is international. So its hard to identify the streetnumber.